# Group Rows Over Multiple Date Ranges

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, rank, date-range

I'm trying to solve what I believe to be (at least) two problems at once with this one, so there may already exist answers that partially answer this question, but I do not fundamentally understand the concept of what I'm trying to do with the data to get it into the final form that I desire.

The problem: I have three grains of data (let's just call them Gas, Liquid, Solid) that occur over a larger period of time, let's call that the Observation Period. The ask is for GasPeriod data to be displayed for the observation period if it is present, then Liquid, then Solid. For a given state, there would only ever be 0 or 1 active records.

```
Gas  X----X       X----X    X---------X 1
Liq  X-------X    X--------XX---------X 2
Sol  X--------------XX----------------X 3

Need 1----12-23--31----12--21---------1
```

What I need is to reduce those 8 ranges (3 GasPeriod, 3 LiquidPeriod, 2 SolidPeriod) into 6 rows with 6 date ranges and the data from the "winning" row to persist the PeriodTemp and Description for the given overlapping period of time.

Any solutions would be helpful, but I'd greatly appreciate any breakdowns of the actual problem here as well so I can educate myself on what I'm doing. I suspect the problem steps involved are:

- Return 8 rows for the Observation Period (must involve a union on GasPeriod, LiquidPeriod and SolidPeriod?)
- Group the rows by date range and rank them (I've seen solutions that involved `LAG` and `DENSE_RANK` but I'm not familiar with the latter and I've only used `LAG` to solve a different problem so it's confusing me a bit how it works.
- Pick the winning record for the given date range (I assume this is solved using a sub-query)

*Edited for clarity*

```
create table ObservationPeriod (
    ObservationPeriodId    BIGINT    IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL,
    BusinessKey            BIGINT    NOT NULL,
    Effective              DATETIME2 NOT NULL,
    Expiry                 DATETIME2 NOT NULL
)

create table GasPeriod (
    GasPeriodId            BIGINT    IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL,
    BusinessKey            BIGINT    NOT NULL,
    PeriodTemp             DECIMAL (11, 5) NOT NULL,
    Description            NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    Effective              DATETIME2 NOT NULL,
    Expiry                 DATETIME2 NOT NULL
)

create table LiquidPeriod (
    LiquidPeriodId         BIGINT    IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL,
    BusinessKey            BIGINT    NOT NULL,
    PeriodTemp             DECIMAL (11, 5) NOT NULL,
    Description            NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    Effective              DATETIME2 NOT NULL,
    Expiry                 DATETIME2 NOT NULL
)

create table SolidPeriod (
    SolidPeriodId          BIGINT    IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL,
    BusinessKey            BIGINT    NOT NULL,
    PeriodTemp             DECIMAL (11, 5) NOT NULL,
    Description            NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    Effective              DATETIME2 NOT NULL,
    Expiry                 DATETIME2 NOT NULL
)

create table ObservationPeriodObserved (
    ObservationPeriodObservedId BIGINT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    BusinessKey            BIGINT    NOT NULL,
    PeriodTemp             DECIMAL (11, 5) NOT NULL,
    Description            NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    Effective              DATETIME2 NOT NULL,
    Expiry                 DATETIME2 NOT NULL
)
```

#### ObservationPeriod Data

| ObservationPeriodId | BusinessKey | Effective | Expiry |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 24 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-12-31 |

#### GasPeriod Data

| GasPeriodId | BusinessKey | PeriodTemp | Description | Effective | Expiry |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 24 | 101.328 | first g | 2020-09-30 | 2021-03-31 |
| 2 | 24 | 102.456 | second g | 2021-06-01 | 2021-07-31 |
| 3 | 24 | 100.011 | third g | 2021-09-01 | 9999-12-31 |

#### LiquidPeriod Data

| LiquidPeriodId | BusinessKey | PeriodTemp | Description | Effective | Expiry |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 24 | 98.99 | first l | 2021-01-01 | 2021-04-30 |
| 2 | 24 | 98.76 | second l | 2021-06-01 | 2021-08-31 |
| 3 | 24 | 99.978 | third l | 2021-09-01 | 9999-12-31 |

#### SolidPeriod Data

| SolidPeriodId | BusinessKey | PeriodTemp | Description | Effective | Expiry |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 24 | -0.145 | first s | 2021-01-01 | 2021-06-30 |
| 2 | 24 | -0.987 | second s | 2021-07-01 | 9999-12-31 |

#### ObvservationPeriodObserved Data

| ObvservationPeriodObservedIdId | BusinessKey | PeriodTemp | Description | Effective | Expiry |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 24 | 101.328 | first g | 2021-01-01 | 2021-03-31 |
| 2 | 24 | 98.99 | first l | 2021-04-01 | 2021-04-30 |
| 3 | 24 | -0.145 | first s | 2021-05-01 | 2021-05-31 |
| 4 | 24 | 102.456 | second g | 2021-06-01 | 2021-07-31 |
| 5 | 24 | 98.76 | second l | 2021-08-01 | 2021-08-31 |
| 6 | 24 | 100.011 | third g | 2021-09-01 | 2021-12-31 |

The idea is that for a given row in ObservationPeriod, there are many associated periods of time between the three aforementioned grains, but only one should ever be recorded as a subset of an ObservationPeriod for a given period of time.

Please also assume that there must be separate granularity here and that this problem cannot be solved away by getting this data into the same table -- it cannot. I can't use the actual business model here so I'm trying to get as close as I can conceptually.

Comment: Can you share some sample data and expected results in text format or DDL to create your scenario?

Comment: Not entirely clear what data you have and what logic you are trying to achieve. Sample input and expected output as proper `create table/insert` would help immensely

Comment: Added psuedo `create table` DDLs. The final insert would be into `ObservationPeriodObserved`, where I want to insert the 6 rows.

Comment: Example data added

Comment: `DECIMAL(3,8)` ? ? typo ?

Comment: @Squirrel -- yes thank you, I've fixed it to what I'm actually using for my real field.

Comment: Should row 6 in `ObvservationPeriodObserved Data` have an Expiry date of `2021-12-31` while the Gas period date in row 3 with the same description has an Expiry date of `9999-12-31`?

Comment: @ggordon Yes, the idea is that the ObservationPeriod is an encapsulating period of time, so when it terms we do not want to capture any additional data for that period. I probably should have thrown an ObservationPeriodId in ObservationPeriodObserved to indicate that relationship. The same would apply to the Effective value of row 1 if they were not all starting on 2021-01-01.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following approach starts by creating a union of the three datasets `Gas`, `Liquid` and `Solid`. In this union an addition column is created `PeriodPriority` which will assist in choosing the winning row. I've interpreted the winning row as a period entry occurring within the observational period, is the most recent and has not expired and will be chosen based on the rank of `Gas`-`1`, `Liquid`-`2` and `Solid`-`3`. This forms the basis of the `DENSE_RANK` window function as it is ordered by recent expired date and the `PeriodPriority`. Since this winning record may have a date exceeding the observational period, I used a case expression to ensure that the value inserted was within the observational period.

Although there is only one Observational period I have still included the where clause `WHERE op.ObservationPeriodId=1` which you may update/remove as desired. I also joined on `BusinessKey` as I am not sure whether this will change throughout your entire set. If `BusinessKey` never changes, then this may be omitted from the join expression.

The resulting query currently looks like this

```sql
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY c.Effective, c.Expiry ) as ObservationPeriodObservedId,
    c.BusinessKey,
    c.PeriodTemp, 
    c.Description,
    c.Effective,
    CASE 
        WHEN c.Expiry >= op.Expiry THEN op.Expiry
        ELSE c.Expiry
    END as Expiry
FROM (
    SELECT 
        *,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY t.Expiry DESC, t.PeriodPriority ) rk
    FROM ( 
        SELECT 
            BusinessKey,PeriodTemp, Description,Effective,Expiry, 1 as PeriodPriority 
        FROM GasPeriod
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 
            BusinessKey,PeriodTemp, Description,Effective,Expiry, 2 
        FROM LiquidPeriod
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 
            BusinessKey,PeriodTemp, Description,Effective,Expiry, 3 
        FROM SolidPeriod
    ) t
) c
INNER JOIN ObservationPeriod op ON c.BusinessKey=op.BusinessKey AND
                                   op.Effective <= c.Effective AND
                                   (op.Expiry >= c.Expiry OR rk=1)
WHERE op.ObservationPeriodId=1
ORDER BY c.Effective, c.Expiry
```

and the insert statement

```sql
INSERT INTO ObservationPeriodObserved (BusinessKey, PeriodTemp, Description, Effective, Expiry)
SELECT 
    c.BusinessKey,
    c.PeriodTemp, 
    c.Description,
    c.Effective,
    CASE 
        WHEN c.Expiry >= op.Expiry THEN op.Expiry
        ELSE c.Expiry
    END as Expiry
FROM (
    SELECT 
        *,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY t.Expiry DESC, t.PeriodPriority ) rk
    FROM ( 
        SELECT 
            BusinessKey,PeriodTemp, Description,Effective,Expiry, 1 as PeriodPriority 
        FROM GasPeriod
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 
            BusinessKey,PeriodTemp, Description,Effective,Expiry, 2 
        FROM LiquidPeriod
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 
            BusinessKey,PeriodTemp, Description,Effective,Expiry, 3 
        FROM SolidPeriod
    ) t
) c
INNER JOIN ObservationPeriod op ON c.BusinessKey=op.BusinessKey AND
                                   op.Effective <= c.Effective AND
                                   (op.Expiry >= c.Expiry OR rk=1)
WHERE op.ObservationPeriodId=1
ORDER BY c.Effective, c.Expiry
```

generates the desired results.

[View working db fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ef2ec62a4d1abb94ca155fe8596f0858)

#### Edit 1 - Consecutive Effective, Expiry Dates

As per the updated question and comment, I have modified the above to utilize `LAG` along with `DATE_ADD` to provide consecutive dates. The Insert  query (latter part is a SELECT) is included below along with an updated db fiddle which provides the desired results. The exception here is `record 1` of `SolidPeriod` that had an end date of `2021-06-30`. When this date was changed to `2021-05-31` as in your desired results, the query corrected the 1 date that was not as expected. If there are additional considerations here or there was an error in the sample data, please let me know. I made the adjustment to the sample data instead of an adhoc calculation as I could not assume some logic to make a change as such (i.e. on an arbitrary record subtract 1 month). Let me know whether this works for you and advise further.

```sql
INSERT INTO ObservationPeriodObserved (BusinessKey, PeriodTemp, Description, Effective, Expiry)

    SELECT 
        c.BusinessKey,
        c.PeriodTemp, 
        c.Description,
        CASE
            WHEN LAG(c.Expiry) OVER (ORDER BY c.Effective, c.Expiry) IS NULL THEN op.Effective
            ELSE DATEADD(DAY,1,LAG(c.Expiry) OVER (ORDER BY c.Effective, c.Expiry))
        END as Effective,
        CASE 
            WHEN c.Expiry >= op.Expiry THEN op.Expiry
            ELSE c.Expiry
        END as Expiry
        
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            *,
            DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY t.Expiry DESC, t.PeriodPriority ) rk
        FROM ( 
            SELECT 
                BusinessKey,PeriodTemp, Description,Effective,Expiry, 1 as PeriodPriority 
            FROM GasPeriod
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 
                BusinessKey,PeriodTemp, Description,Effective,Expiry, 2 
            FROM LiquidPeriod
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 
                BusinessKey,PeriodTemp, Description,Effective,Expiry, 3 
            FROM SolidPeriod
        ) t
    ) c
    INNER JOIN ObservationPeriod op ON c.BusinessKey=op.BusinessKey AND
                                       op.Effective <= c.Effective AND
                                       (op.Expiry >= c.Expiry OR rk=1)
    WHERE op.ObservationPeriodId=1
    ORDER BY c.Effective, c.Expiry
```

[View Demo DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4cc6fb4868017969d3a1f7445999346c)

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: This is great. The only piece I don’t think I’m following is the Expiry logic of >= OR rank = 1. What does this do, and if I have the same requirement for Effective, does the same trick work?

Comment: `op.Expiry >= c.Expiry` checks to ensure that the records from the union are within the observational period i.e. the expiry date of the observational period is greater than or equal to the expiry date of the gas/liquid/solid records, this could also be rewritten as `c.Expiry <= op.Expiry `. The `rk` has the rank or the winning row value. The idea is that the winning row value will be current/within/or have an effective date within the period but may not be expired as yet as it is current, having a value of `9999-12-31`.

Comment: Instead of filtering on this value of `9999-12-31` then having to limit by the `1` winning record, the `DENSE_RANK` function does the work for us an assigns a rank of `1` which I am filtering by in this expression.

Comment: You could apply the same approach for effective if testing it provides the desired results but I hope the comments here have provided some more clarity on it's inclusion and how it helps to garner that "winning value". Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Yes I think the gap I was struggling with was when I only had a 3, how I do know it’s the winner (I had an identical solution for the union part), but DENSE_RANK() must force that to the top of the group so that we always end up with a 1, which makes sense. I’m confident I can get Effective to work, this gets me most of the way home. Thanks again.

Comment: After looking at this more thoroughly on a computer screen this morning, this answer gets close but does not fully solve the issue. There is a problem with the aggregated Effective values in the results -- they do not conform to the end date of the previous row + 1 day as they should to make a timeline.

Comment: @JustinGrahn I've updated the answer. Let me know if this works for you.